# simplify ssh hostnames with wildcard

Tags: linux, ssh

I got many servers with names ending in 001, 002, 003 and I want to rename them into something simpler; something like this:

```
Host server*
User user
HostName server-xxx-yyy-zzz-*

Host client*
User user
HostName client-xxx-yyy-zzz-*
```

And then `ssh server001` is executed like `ssh server-xxx-yyy-zzz-001`

Is there any way to do this with only ssh-config? can I do some maneuver in /etc/hosts? or I have to create a script to generate the config for each host?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I put the new names in `/etc/hosts` because I also need them:

- as `ping` targets
- in browser URLs (admin consoles, or testing servers)
- in DB connection
- in Git URLs.

Once you have done that you only need one generic entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host client* server*
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # if the same everywhere
```

Of course SSH will pester you once for each new name, to add the host key to known_hosts.

Comment: I ask if this can be done using **wildcards** or something short and smart. If I flush 1k hostnames in `/etc/hosts`, it is like I am moving the problem from `~/.ssh/config` to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: You didn't define "many" :) All I could guess was `1  < several < many < billions`. So what you want to do is run your own DNS with some code to replace names on the fly and forward the request to the official DNS. But I don't know is such DNS exists.